# scp with variable driven server is not working

Tags: scp, rhel8, sh

```
#!/bin/ksh/
SERVER_NAME=bcpstd.root.net
FOLDER_ROOT_PATH=/data/feed/daily
CURDATE=`date +"%Y%0m%0d"`

scp gfstd@${SERVER_NAME}:${FOLDER_ROOT_PATH}/details_all_data_${CURDATE}.dat.gz /local/FILE_UPLOADS/I_FILES/
```

When i run this it is asking password

```
bash-4.4$ sh data_load.sh
Password:
```

But the same script if turn all to hard code, it works fine, not asking for password

```
#!/bin/ksh/
SERVER_NAME=bcpstd.root.net
FOLDER_ROOT_PATH=/data/feed/daily
CURDATE=`date +"%Y%0m%0d"`

scp gfstd@bcpstd.root.net:/data/feed/daily/details_all_data_20231228.dat.gz /local/FILE_UPLOADS/I_FILES/
```

When i run this like above hardcoded it is working fine

```
bash-4.4$ sh data_load.sh
details_all_data_20231228.dat.gz                                                                                                                                                                                                100%  596MB  39.2MB/s   00:15
```

Comment: `scp gfstdsrc@` vs `scp gfstd@` - different user for a start

Comment: What @JaromandaX said and additionally your script header looks odd with the trailing slash on `#!/bin/ksh/`

Comment: @JaromandaX That was typo. actual user name is gfstd

Comment: Additionally running a Korn script with sh... Which way is it? There's a number of inconsistencies here, which you should address first.